# Best data structure for insert/update/delete and search of 2d point

Tags: indexing, data-structures, webgl

I have a infrastructure for massive entities on a GIS map - using the graphic card for drawing (WebGL).

Today, I'm using quad-tree for indexing the data and querying - for selection/drawing purposes.

Recently I've found a way to enable my users to update the location of the entities and draw the change very fast. for example updating 15000 locations, and redrawing took less then 0.05 ms.

The problem now is updating my data structure. It is very very slow.

I've ran over many data structures, such as R-tree, B-Tree and more.. but not yet found satisfied result.

My question is

what is the optimal data structure for 2d points from performances point of view, for inserting/updating and query (by distance from point, rectangle) ?

Maybe there is a web gl solution for this ?

Comment: do you have LOD system which quad tree depth represents? or it is pure 2d?

Comment: Try a simple uniform hash grid. It has O(1) insert/delete as oppose to O(log n) in any tree based structure. Query is also O(c) if your tile size is reasonable for the data you provide.

Comment: My quad tree is pure single LOD. @WacławJasper Thanks for the tip. I will try and update the results

Answer (score 0):

> what is the optimal data structure for 2d points from performances
>   point of view, for inserting/updating and query (by distance from
>   point, rectangle) ?

It's hard to find a data structure that satisfies all of these beautifully. Typically for searches to be fastest, insertion has to be slower, for insertion to be faster, searches have to be slower, so it's a balancing act.

However, given your needs, a simple NxM grid might actually be ideal. I come originally from a gaming background where sprites can be moving at every single frame. Quad-trees are often too expensive for such dynamic content that wants to update the structure every single frame. As a result, a simple NxM grid often works better for those cases.

The NxM grid can do a rectangular query potentially even faster than the quad-tree, as it simply has to determine which grid cells overlap the rectangle and then simply check the elements within the cells to see if the overlap/are inside the rectangle. Same goes for a search within a radial parameter (circle).

Insertion and removal is dirt cheap since we only need to update the cells in which the elements overlap. If you're dealing with points, a point only belongs in one cell, and it becomes an extremely simple constant-time operation. In fact, if each point stores a list pointer for the next element, moving it from one cell to another (along with removing it from a cell and inserting it to a cell) only requires changing pointers around -- no memory allocation required. The grid then becomes a grid of head pointers for a singly-linked list.

Another approach is that I imagine you're currently using one massive quad-tree for the entire world. You can use a hybrid of these techniques by using a quad-tree to represent a small region, e.g., with quad-trees tiled together to form a grid of quad-trees. This can significantly reduce the cost to update a quad-tree for a specific region since each quad-tree stores only the data for that region.